# GTSummary: How to order table by one column

Tags: r

let's say I have this dummy dataframe and create a table summary:

```
df <- tibble(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), value = c("h", "h", "h", "b", "h")) %>% group_by(group) %>% gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = group)
```

[image]

I now want to change to order of rows according to the frequency of column "a". That is, row with `value = h` should be the first row.

Is there any way to achieve this without changing the levels of the value row?

Answer (score 1):

An option could be `sort` by column "value" of its "frequency" like this:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
df <- tibble(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), value = c("h", "h", "h", "b", "h")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(by = group, sort = value ~ "frequency")

df
```

Output:

[image]